# angularjs not working in my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have added module and a controller but its not working.kindly point out my errors so I can remove them.

```
var app=angular.module("hello",[]);
app.controller("func",function()
{
    this.products=gems;
});
var gems=[
    name:Azhar,
    gpa:2.8,
    institute:UCP
    ];

**html code**

//html code of what I have done so far.

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="world.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

<html>
<body ng-app="hello">
<div ng-controller="func">

    {{products.name}};


</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you downloaded and added angualr.min.js in your workspace ??

Comment: what is the error in the browser console?

Comment: browser didn't show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `Scope` variable in your controller.

```
var app=angular.module("hello",[]);
app.controller("func",function($scope)
{
    $scope.products=gems;
});
```

Also, you are not using the array variable correctly.

Add `ng-repeat`to access the array elements.

```
<div ng-controller="func">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        {{product.name}};
    </div
</div>
```

this should work for you

**EDIT**

According to AngularJS documentation:

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the `ng-controller`
>   directive, Angular will instantiate a `new Controller object`, using the
>   specified Controller's constructor function. A new child `scope` will be
>   created and made available as an injectable parameter to the
>   `Controller's constructor` function as `$scope`.

For more info please see [AngularJS controller documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected your code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="world.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="hello">
<div ng-controller="func">
    {{products.name}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module("hello", []);
app.controller("func", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var gems = {
        name: 'Azhar',
        gpa: 2.8,
        institute: 'UCP'
    };

    $scope.products = gems;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things you need to fix:

1. change `gems` from `Array` to `Object`
2. set `$scope.products` instead of `this.products`
3. assign `gems` to `$scope.products` only after it is defined
4. set string values of `gems` using quotation marks

here is a working example after these fixes:

```js
var gems = {
  name:'Azhar',
  gpa:2.8,
  institute:'UCP'
};
var app=angular.module("hello",[]);
app.controller("func", function($scope){
  $scope.products=gems;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="hello">
  <div ng-controller="func">
    {{products.name}};
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working but can you please tell me the logic behind $scope variable why we can't perform it without it

Comment: yes, `$scope` is the "glue" in between your controller and your view, and that is the way to bind controller variables to the view. read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

I see many problems with your code. I suggest you to follow a [good tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01) on angularjs.

.

### You are not using $scope at all

You can think as $scope as a common object you share with your current controller and the HTML view.
Everything it's in the $scope can be manipulated in a "double binding" way between controller and HTML (it can edited from both ways).

For example, this is your code:

```
app.controller("func",function()
{
    this.products = gems; //don't do this, you html will don't ever know what "products" is.
});
```

that should be replaced by:

```
app.controller("func",function($scope)
{
    $scope.products = [{name:Azhar,gpa:2.8,institute:UCP}]; //note the $scope sintax, and the correct way to initialize an array of objects ({}).
});
```

.

### You are not using correctly arrays in HTML

if "products" it's an array, then `{{products.name}};` will not simply work, because an array needs an index to work with. For example ,`{{products[0].name}};` will give you the name of the first element of your array.

**But**

Angularjs gives you a better way to approach with arrays, by using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
   {{product.name}}
</div>
```

will iterate trought your array and display the name of every product you have inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in head and use controllerAs as shown below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="world.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

<body ng-app="hello">
  <div ng-controller="func as prod">
    {{prod.products.name}};
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```